# Adding column in mysql table is not working?

Tags: php

This is what i have so far i am not getting any error. But the column adding doesn't work?
It doesn't appear in my database.
What should i do?

```
 <?php

      $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","texaco","texaco","texaco");

      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

      elseif (mysqli_query("ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test varchar(255) NOT NULL")) {
          echo "Table creation failed: (" . mysqli_errno . ") " . mysqli_error;
      }


      else {
      header("Location: inloggen.php");
      }



      /* ;
        mysqli_query($sql);

       */

      ?>
```

Comment: paste the mysqli_error and mysqli_error_no

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a management frontend for MySQL, it's not a database itself. You are directly working with the database, phpMyAdmin is not involved. I corrected your title to reflect this.

Comment: Why are you correcting things you must help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you never passed your db connection to the query:

```
elseif (mysqli_query("ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test varchar(255) NOT NULL"))
```

do:

```
elseif (mysqli_query($mysqli, "ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test varchar(255) NOT NULL"))
```

Consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Plus, it is best to add `exit;` after header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

```
header("Location: inloggen.php");
exit;
```

However, I wouldn't use an `elseif` and I have no idea why you would want to do that. Just check if the query was successfully executed.

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test varchar(255) NOT NULL");

    if(!$query){
       echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
    }

else{
    header("Location: inloggen.php");
    exit;
}
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: *Pretty much Sam* @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  elseif (mysqli_query($mysqli,"ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD test varchar(255) NOT NULL")) {
       //do something when column add
  } else {
       echo "Column creation failed: (" . mysqli_errno . ") " . mysqli_error;
    }
```

In first line change USERNAME for name of user with privileges in the database of alter table, change PASSWORD for the password of user and DATABASE for the name of database.

If this not work check the privileges of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

your query is correct. 
I think your user **texaco** don't have a privilege in phpmyadmin for Alter Table.

- Go in your phpmyAdmin
- Add texaco all privileges for your db.

Comment: I have no errors man. Everything is working fine he reads the script and no errors. But the column doesnt appear in the database

Comment: @JapanseMixxx man, add in your php this code : This always works for me:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`
However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

`display_errors = on`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all m8 it workes man none of your answers helped this was the finally code for you mann::::

```
<?php

  $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","texaco","texaco","texaco");
  $kolomnaam = $_POST['kolomnaam'];
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  elseif (mysqli_query($mysqli, "ALTER TABLE prijzen ADD $kolomnaam varchar(255) NOT NULL")) {
      echo "Table creation failed: (" .  mysqli_errno . ") " . mysqli_error;
  }


  else {
  header("Location: inloggen.php");
  }



  ?>
```